# How to achieve .isHighlighted animation in a Custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uibutton, highlight

**Preamble** (page down after code for the actual problem):

I have a custom `UIButton` class in which I replaced the ordinary `UIButton` `isHighlighted` animation behavior with this behavior:

When the user's finger is actually on the button (ie. highlighting the button), a stroked outline (square border) will appear around the button.  When they are no longer touching the button, the outline disappears.

Also, I have replaced the normal `isSelected` behavior (background goes blue) with this:

An outline identical to the one used with `isHighlighted` is drawn, except it is slightly thicker and always there as long as `isSelected = true`, and it is not there when `isSelected = false`.

This works, and this is how I did it:

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    // BUTTON TYPES:
    // Gorsh, enums sure would be swell here. :T
    // 1 : plus
    // 2 : minus
    // 3 : etc etc....
    @IBInspectable
    var thisButtonsType: Int = 1 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var fillColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var strokeColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let unitOfMeasure = bounds.width / 5

        // draw outline in case we are selected / highlighted
        if (isSelected || isHighlighted) {

            let tempPath = BezierPathFactory.outline(totalWidth: bounds.width)
            if (isSelected) {tempPath.lineWidth = 4.0}
            strokeColor.setStroke()
            tempPath.stroke()

        }

        // initialize path object
        var path = UIBezierPath()

        // get the path corresponding to our button type
        switch thisButtonsType {

        case 1:
            path = BezierPathFactory.plus(gridSpacing: unitOfMeasure)
        case 2:
            path = BezierPathFactory.minus(gridSpacing: unitOfMeasure)

        default: print("hewo!")

        }

        fillColor.setFill()

        path.fill()


    }

}
```

Once again, that code works but ...

What I would really like is if that isHighlighted border outline would gradually fade away after the touch finishes.

Note: In case you're wondering why I would do things this way... I plan to implement lots of different button types... all with different icons "printed" on them... but I want them all to follow these basic behaviors.  Only a couple of them are "toggle" buttons that ever become selected, so there IS a use for the highlight fade.

I already know how to do animations... but it's just doing my head in trying to think how to do that in this context.

I wish I could get the UIButton source code.

Is there a way that the fade animation could be added relatively simply to my above code without completely changing the design pattern?  Am I going to have to start using some other feature of core graphics like layers?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you offer the code of `BezierPathFactory` class. BTW, I think using layer would be easier.

Comment: I suppose I can... it just returns a path, though. =T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do the following:

1. Create a subclass of `UIButton` which adds and manages a sublayer of class `CAShapeLayer` for the outline the button.
2. Draw the outline the outline into the shape layer.
3. Ensure that the layer resizes with the view: Overwrite `layoutSubviews` of your view such that it updates the frame of the layer and updates the path for the outline.
4. You should observe or overwrite the `state` property of `UIControl` (which is an ancestor of `UIButton`) to notice the state changes.
5. Use property animations (`CABasicAnimation`) for the opacity of the shape layer to fade the outline in and out.